# Dataflow - XML Source - Python - How?

Tags: python, xml, apache-beam, dataflow

I'm trying to source an XML file into my dataflow code.  I see java has a built in XMLIo but Python doesn't?  I'm also struggling to understand what are the initial steps to ParDo/DoFn it myself.  This is an example of the XML file below.  My pipeline below when parsing .csv I understand but I'm not understanding how to start with an XML source.  Do I need to manually create a PCollection and go from there?

My goal is to return each element as a tuple.  The key would be the country name and each element after (in a nested array) would be the values.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data>
```

```
def run():
   argv = [
      '--project={0}'.format(PROJECT),
      '--staging_location=gs://{0}/'.format(BUCKET),
      '--temp_location=gs://{0}/'.format(BUCKET),
      '--runner=DataflowRunner'
      #'--runner=DirectRunner'
   ]

   p = beam.Pipeline(argv=argv)

   (p
      | 'ReadFromGCS' >> beam.io.textio.ReadFromText('gs://{0}/example.csv'.format(BUCKET))
-[SNIP]-
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will collect each country information.

The output is a list of tuples.

The first element in the tuple is the country name and the second element is a list of the other country properties.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


xml = '''<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data>'''

result = []
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for country in root.findall('.//country'):
    result.append((country.attrib['name'],[x.text if x.text else x.attrib for x in list(country)]))
print(result)
```

output

```
[('Liechtenstein', ['1', '2008', '141100', {'name': 'Austria', 'direction': 'E'}, {'name': 'Switzerland','direction': 'W'}]), ('Singapore', ['4', '2011', '59900', {'name': 'Malaysia', 'direction': 'N'}]), ('Panama', ['68', '2011', '13600', {'name': 'Costa Rica', 'direction': 'W'}, {'name': 'Colombia', 'direction': 'E'}])]
```

Comment: Thanks balderman!  Would you happen to know how this would work in a beam pipeline?  If I form a PCollection off of tuple with all the country entries (could be hundreds of not thousands in the production dataset I'm using) would my next transform essentially need to transfer this single row/tuple to all worker nodes to process?

Comment: I am not familiar with beam. If you find my xml parsing useful - feel free to vote up.

Comment: Will do!  Let me test it out and give props where they're due :)

Comment: This indeed helped me write a DoFn to parse the XML.  This was a big piece of the puzzle, thanks so much!!!